# Opc Ua FileSysem with CallMethod occurs 'The value supplied for the attribute is not of the same type as the attribute's value.' in VB

Tags: vb.net, opc-ua

I am working Opc Ua with VB and tried to delete a file from Opc Ua FileSyetem by CallMethod as below program:

```
Dim FileFolderObjectId As String = "ns=2;s=Sinumerik/FileSystem/Part Program"
Dim methodDeleteNodeId As String = "ns=2;s=Sinumerik/FileSystem/Part Program.Delete"
Dim SourcePartProgramId As New OpcArgumentCollection()
Dim objectNodeId As New OpcNodeId("Sinumerik/FileSystem/Part Program/T_5M.MPF")
Dim Argument1 As New OpcArgument("InputArgument", objectNodeId, False)
SourcePartProgramId.Add(Argument1)
client.Connect()
' Delete a file "T_5M.MPF" under NodeId "Sinumerik/FileSystem/Part Program"
client.CallMethod(FileFolderObjectId, methodDeleteNodeId, SourcePartProgramId)'
```

After debug run, the error message occurred 'The value supplied for the attribute is not of the same type as the attribute's value.' at the line "client.CallMethod(FileFolderObjectId, methodDeleteNodeId, SourcePartProgramId).

Do you know what is wrong with the data type of "inputArgument"?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Single brackets for coding line blocks are request by post editing, it doesn't belong to original program codings. Only the double-bracket was missing at end of T_5M.MPF what you have corrected it. I have checked over the OpcArgument class and cannot see any wrong attribute value with OpcNodeId data type.  Would you check the OpcArgument object is correct for this CallMethod?